# $Http.get(), how to deal with 404 response from WebAPI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, http, web-applications

On my web application I perform a `GET` command to a remote HTTP WebAPI service

```
$http.get(url).then(function(data) { do_something(); });
```

everything works fine when the WebAPI returns some data, however the function doesn't seem to trigger when the WebAPI return a 404 error (no data to display).
How can I set a callback for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$http.get(url).then(function(data) {
  do_something();
}, function(err) {
  // your error function
  if (err.status == 404) {
    do_something_else();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think for the 404 responses, best thing is to show proper not found page. In angularjs you can intercept the response with $injector service. So you can create a service which look for 404 response and show 404 page.

```
    angular.module('mymodule')

    .service('APIInterceptor', function( $injector) {
      return {
       'request': function(config){
           // request logic goes here.
       },
       'responseError' : function(response){
          if (response.status === 404) {
            $injector.get('$state').go('error_500');
          }
        return response;
       }
     };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`$http` returns status code as the second argument.

```
$http.get(url)
  .success(function(data, status) {
      alert(status);
  })
  .error(function(data, status) {
      alert('Error with status code: ' + status); 
  });
```

`status` – `{number}` – HTTP status code of the response.

However, if the status is an error status, such as 404, then the error block will be called